# Lagrange multipliers: The restriction «$x$ is in a box in $\mathbb{R}^n$».

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to maximise a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with the restriction that an optimal point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is contained in some $n$-dimensional box in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e.
$$
x_0 \in [a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2] \times \cdots \times [a_n,b_n]
$$
for real numbers $a_1 < b_1$ and $a_2 < b_2$ and $\cdots$ and $a_n < b_n$. Is there a smart way to reformulate this restriction in terms of a function $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^c$ such that $g(x_0) = 0$ for the purpose of the Lagrange multiplier theorem? If you can see that it is impossible for some reason, it would be a delight to learn that too.

---

EDIT: The following is known as the Lagrange multiplier theorem[[1]](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/mathematical-methods-and-models-for-economists/B4A6CCAA2BD7F44A4369CCC90E7DC1E9).

**Theorem** Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb {R} ^{n}\to \mathbb {R} ^{c}$ be differentiable functions. Let $x_0$ be global maximum of  $f$ on $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ such that $\mathrm{rank} (Dg)(x_0) = c < n$. There exists unique $ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{c}$ such that $D f ( x_0 ) = λ^T D g ( x_0 )$.

Comment: It would help if you clarified what is "the Lagrange multiplier theorem" as well as any other assumptions about $f$ (differentiable? convex? concave?) and/or more detail on what you are trying to do. Lagrange multipliers typically involve constraints and so one way to approach the problem is to explicitly turn the box constraints into inequality constraints on the decision vector $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ such as $x_1 \leq b_1$, $x_1 \geq a_1$ and so on.

Comment: @Michael added.

Comment: That theorem looks like it is oriented for solving problems that find $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to maximize $f(x)$ subject to equality constraints $g_1(x)=0, ..., g_c(x)=0$. If desired, you could convert all inequality constraints into equality constraints with "auxiliary variables" $y_i$ and $z_i$.  So the inequality constraint $x_i \leq b_i$ is equivalent to the equality constraint $x_i-b_i +y_i^2=0$. This unfortunately turns a "nice and convex" inequality constraint into a nonconvex equality constraint, but it seems the best we can do if we need $x_i, y_i, z_i$ to all be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Michael what is the definition of $y_i$?

Comment: It is a new variable that you add.  Do you agree that $x_i\leq b_i$ if and only if there is a $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_i-b_i+y_i^2=0$?

Comment: @Michael without a formula for $y_i,z_i$ in terms of $a_i,b_i$, the function $g_i$ is unknown.

Comment: Do you agree that $x_i \leq b_i$ if and only if there is a $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_i-b_i+y_i^2=0$?  If you agree then indeed you have an explicit formula for a $g_i$ function that enforces a desired constraint.  The point here is that you are constructing $g_i$ functions that turn the desired inequality constraints into equality constraints. You have $2n$ inequality constraints so you should expect to have $2n$ such $g_i$ functions, or call then $g_i$ and $h_i$ for easier notation.

Comment: @Michael, I agree that such points $y_i$ exist. Now tell me $g_1(7)$ in case $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. You should need luck. Conversation closed.

Comment: The functions $g_i$ are functions of $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3n}$, it does not make sense to evaluate a function that expects an $(3n)$-dimensional vector as input with the scalar "7" as input.

Comment: The question defines $f$ and $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, they are $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and $g(x_1, ..., x_n)$.  Assuming $n>1$, there is no such thing as $g(7)$. Note that $x_0 = (x_{01}, x_{02},..., x_{0n}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which may have caused some confusion.

Comment: Your responses are unusual, are you asking me to explicitly define the $g_1(x;y;z)$ function?  This is very easy to do, and I thought the answer was obvious from my above comments (I gave the function already but I did not call it $g_i$), and evaluating at given numerical values of $(x;y;z)$ is also easy.    I wonder at your responses and also if this is a homework question, it has the flavor of a basic homework question.  Anyway I do not understand the hostility in your responses.

Comment: It all makes sense to me @Michael. Mikkel Rev I suggest you reread the comments of Michael from top to botton as these specify how one would go about converting the box constraints (which are inequality constraints) to equality constraints. This in turn would let you apply the theorem you mention.